# similar words to "research", but less seriously

Tags: word-request

I want to express that:

> After doing some [research], I've got my own conclusion about how I should eat the apple.

I want to seek a word which is less "strong" than [research]. Because in my mind, [research] is meant to be used in some very strict areas. For example, do some [science research], [mathematic research], [astronomy research].

Obviously, "how I should eat the apple" is not something serious and strict. So I want a more appropriate word.

Is "study" more appropriate?

> After doing some [study], I've got my own conclusion about how I should eat the apple.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can say "after some digging"

Answer (score 1):

Research is actually more appropriate than study here. Research need not be in any way formal, and study sounds much more formal than research.

Comment: I agree, "research" is also used in infomal contexts. If the context is serious enough to bother writing about, the word fits.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that "research" has very formal/academic connotations.

"study" is less formal, but still academic, or to do with reading, experimenting, and collecting knowledge. "study" still seems a bit rigorous for discovering casual apple-eating preferences.

If you would like terms that are less writing/reading oriented, "some experiments," or "some taste-tests" may fit.

A slightly more elaborate change: "After sampling several varieties..." or "After trying several different kinds of apples..."  These examples are a bit longer, but the connotations are also much less formal than "research" and "study".